# Localize views menus links

Tags: 7, routes, users, i18n-l10n

I need a way to *localize* menu Items pointing to Views in a menu that has field translation.

I cannot create them neither from views nor manually (weird access denied messages).

EDIT: Here comes the original post. The title was "Translate the main menu with preserving English in case the translation is missing". I learned a thing or two in the process ;-)

I think I am doing something basically wrong...
I have set up a basic multilingual site with fields (entity) translation. Now, all works fine up to the menus. If I translate the menus, however, only the menu links that *have actually been translated* show up in the other languages. What's more, the menu structure does in other languages does not preserve the weights of the particular links.
What I'd like is to happen is:

1. English (or other provided) menu link show up when no translation is available.
2. The translated links preserve the weights.

Settings the menu links to "language neutral" solved the issue to a point. I cannot apply this practice, however, to views. Menu Items from views have English by default. What's more, when I remove the menu item in Views menu and try to make a  menu item that points to it by path, I get:

> You are not authorized to access this page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should set in the content type translation settings, to show **no fallback language**, and **set all english nodes to English**, rather than Language neutral (if they are such).

Comment: I had more success, to the contrary, putting the links as Language Neutral. The problem, though, is that I get an error message saying I do not have Admin permissions.

Comment: f you wanted to actually show a link for any language, then yes. If you wanted to hide it for other languages, then set it to langauge-specific.

Answer (score 0):

So, my problem was: How to *localize* menu links created by views?

In fact, I could neither create links by views *nor add menus links that point to those views manually (I got access denied messages). 
Eventually I used the Menu Tokens module with paths like `[site-url]\xxx`. This worked.